# Xamarin System.Data.Linq inside PCL

Tags: c#, android, linq, xamarin, system.data

I've got a PCL which includes **System.Data.Linq**(.Mappings) via the dll itself. This works with iOS, Windows and MacOS, but it does not with Android.

### Temp:

I will post the error message as soon as I am back at work, but I remember it was something like *"Could not load file or assembly System.Data.Linq". It was not found*

I know this namespace is not supported inside a PCL, but it is strange that it works (and yes, I made multiple projects with this) in every project type except Xamarin:Android.

Is there anything I could try like implementing the code myself, embed assemblies in native code, or something else?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anything I could try like implementing the code myself, embed assemblies in native code, or something else?

I think no. As you already known, `System.Data.Linq` is unavailable in PCLs, and there is no lambda expressions in Android (or Java) yet. Also we need to respect the design of PCL, it is used to write and build managed assemblies that work on more than one .NET Framework platform. So if the method/dll or something else is not supported in the projects which uses this PCL, then this method/dll should not be placed in PCL.

Also, Xamarin.Forms is designed as a cross-platform UI toolkit that allows developers to easily create native user interface layouts that can be shared across Android, iOS, and Windows Phone. It is mainly target sharing UI. Of course you can also specify the platform when calling method/dll in its PCL, for example like this:

```
#if __MOBILE__
// Xamarin iOS or Android-specific code
#endif
```

For more info about specifying platform, you can refer to [Dealing with Multiple Platforms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_4_-_platform_divergence_abstraction_divergent_implementation/).

Comment: Okay so I will change my code so that every Project will include System.Data.Linq.. Thanks for your answer!